# Yii Framework - Mssql incorrect bracket placement

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, yii

I am having some problems with Mssql 2008 and Yii Framework with incorrect bracket placement when using the query builder.

```
$queryCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$selectArray = array();
$selectArray[] = 't.id';
$selectArray[] = "CASE t.description  WHEN '' THEN t.name ELSE t.name + ' : ' + t.description END AS text";
$queryCommand->select($selectArray);
$queryCommand->from("table t");
```

I get a weird query string.

```
SELECT [t].[id], [CASE] AS [t].[description  WHEN '' THEN t].[name ELSE t].[name + ' : ' + t].[description END AS text]
FROM [table] [t]
```

Is there a better way to do the case?

If I add a SUBSTRING function to the t.description no brackets are added.

```
$queryCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$selectArray = array();
$selectArray[] = 't.id';
$selectArray[] = "CASE t.description  WHEN '' THEN t.name ELSE t.name + ' : ' + SUBSTRING(t.description,0,30) END AS text";
$queryCommand->select($selectArray);
$queryCommand->from("table t");
```

I get

```
SELECT [t].[id], CASE t.description WHEN '' THEN t.name ELSE t.name + ' : ' +    SUBSTRING(t.description,0,30) END AS text
FROM [table] [t]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the array syntax?

Comment: Do you have a logic error as you are checking to see if t.name is an empty string and if it is, then you are just using it. Otherwise, you are concatenating Name & Description. Shouldn't you be checking Description in your case statement?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins Yes there is a reason. I simplified the query to show just the issue.

Comment: @billinkc Thanks, for pointing that out. That isn't how it is in my code. I renamed the tables for the post and mixed them up.